# d3 - legend for parallel coordinate chart not displayed

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a parallel coordinate chart. I want to display a legend. From the example from Bostock's website, I wrote something similar. But, I can only see the colours of the lines being shown and not the text. 
The text is being returned correctly as well. 
What am I performing incorrectly ?

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

svg {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.background path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ddd;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.foreground path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: steelblue;
}

.brush .extent {
  fill-opacity: .3;
  stroke: #fff;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.axis line,
.axis path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.axis text {
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff, 1px 0 0 #fff, 0 -1px 0 #fff, -1px 0 0 #fff;
  cursor: move;
}

.legend rect {
  fill:white;
  stroke:black;
  opacity:0.8;}

</style>
<body>
<div style="width:1140px; height:550px;margin-left:50px;margin-top:50px;" id="chartDiv"></div>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3-legend/1.5.0/d3-legend.js"></script>
<script>

var margin = {top: 30, right: 10, bottom: 10, left: 10},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scale.ordinal().rangePoints([0, width], 1),
    y = {},
    dragging = {};

var line = d3.svg.line(),
    axis = d3.svg.axis().orient("left"),
    background,
    foreground;

var svg = d3.select("#chartDiv").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .domain(['white','other','african-american','hispanic','asian/pacific islander'])
  .range(['#ffae19','#4ca64c','#4682B4','#737373', '#ff4c4c']);

d3.csv("SurvivalProbability.csv", function(error, cars) {

  // Extract the list of dimensions and create a scale for each.
  x.domain(dimensions = d3.keys(cars[0]).filter(function(d) {
    if(d === "Ethnicity") {
        y[d] = d3.scale.ordinal()
          .domain(cars.map(function(p) { return p[d]; }))
          .rangePoints([height, 0]);
    }

    else if(d === "Site") {
        y[d] = d3.scale.ordinal()
          .domain(cars.map(function(p) { return p[d]; }))
          .rangePoints([height, 0]);

    }

    else if(d === "Tcategory") {
        y[d] = d3.scale.ordinal()
          .domain(cars.map(function(p) { return p[d]; }))
          .rangePoints([height, 0]);

    }

    else if(d === "Nodal_Disease") {
        y[d] = d3.scale.ordinal()
          .domain(cars.map(function(p) { return p[d]; }))
          .rangePoints([height, 0]);

    }

    else if(d === "Chemotherapy") {
        y[d] = d3.scale.ordinal()
          .domain(cars.map(function(p) { return p[d]; }))
          .rangePoints([height, 0]);

    }

    else if(d === "Local_Therapy") {
        y[d] = d3.scale.ordinal()
          .domain(cars.map(function(p) { return p[d]; }))
          .rangePoints([height, 0]);

    }
    else {
        y[d] = d3.scale.linear()
          .domain(d3.extent(cars, function(p) { return +p[d]; }))
          .range([height, 0]);
    }

    return true;
}));

  // Add grey background lines for context.
  background = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "background")
    .selectAll("path")
      .data(cars)
    .enter().append("path")
      .attr("d", path);

  // Add blue foreground lines for focus.
  /*foreground = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "foreground")
    .selectAll("path")
      .data(cars)
    .enter().append("path")
      .attr("d", path);*/


        foreground = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "foreground")
    .selectAll("path")
      .data(cars)
    .enter().append("path")
      .attr("d", path)
      .style("stroke", function(d) {
        return color(d.Ethnicity);
      })

  // Add a group element for each dimension.
  var g = svg.selectAll(".dimension")
      .data(dimensions)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "dimension")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d) + ")"; })
      .call(d3.behavior.drag()
        .origin(function(d) { return {x: x(d)}; })
        .on("dragstart", function(d) {
          dragging[d] = x(d);
          background.attr("visibility", "hidden");
        })
        .on("drag", function(d) {
          dragging[d] = Math.min(width, Math.max(0, d3.event.x));
          foreground.attr("d", path);
          dimensions.sort(function(a, b) { return position(a) - position(b); });
          x.domain(dimensions);
          g.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + position(d) + ")"; })
        })
        .on("dragend", function(d) {
          delete dragging[d];
          transition(d3.select(this)).attr("transform", "translate(" + x(d) + ")");
          transition(foreground).attr("d", path);
          background
              .attr("d", path)
            .transition()
              .delay(500)
              .duration(0)
              .attr("visibility", null);
        }));

  // Add an axis and title.
  g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis")
      .each(function(d) { d3.select(this).call(axis.scale(y[d])); })
    .append("text")
      .style("text-anchor", "middle")
      .attr("y", -9)
      .text(function(d) { return d; });

  // Add and store a brush for each axis.
  g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "brush")
      .each(function(d) {
        d3.select(this).call(y[d].brush = d3.svg.brush().y(y[d]).on("brushstart", brushstart).on("brush", brush));
      })
    .selectAll("rect")
      .attr("x", -8)
      .attr("width", 16);

      var legendRectSize = 10;
      var legendSpacing = 100;
      var legend = d3.select('svg')
    .append("g")
    .selectAll("g")
    .data(color.domain())
    .enter()
    .append('g')
      .attr('class', 'legend')
      .attr('transform', function(d, i) {
        var height = legendRectSize;
        var x = 925;
        var y = (i * height) + 50;
        return 'translate(' + x + ',' + y + ')';
    });

    legend.append('rect')
    .attr('width', legendRectSize)
    .attr('height', legendRectSize)
    .style('fill', color)
    .style('stroke', color);

legend.append('text')
    .attr('x', legendRectSize + legendSpacing)
    .attr('y', legendRectSize - legendSpacing)
    .text(function(d) { return d; });

});

function position(d) {
  var v = dragging[d];
  return v == null ? x(d) : v;
}

function transition(g) {
  return g.transition().duration(500);
}

// Returns the path for a given data point.
function path(d) {
  return line(dimensions.map(function(p) { return [position(p), y[p](d[p])]; }));
}

function brushstart() {
  d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();
}

// Handles a brush event, toggling the display of foreground lines.
function brush() {
  var actives = dimensions.filter(function(p) { return !y[p].brush.empty(); }),
      extents = actives.map(function(p) { return y[p].brush.extent(); });
  foreground.style("display", function(d) {
    return actives.every(function(p, i) {
      return extents[i][0] <= d[p] && d[p] <= extents[i][1];
    }) ? null : "none";
  });
}

</script>
```

Comment: Can you include your data file (or a snippet of it) in the question, so that your code may be reproduced?

Comment: Here's the snapshot:

AgeAtTx,Ethnicity,Site,Tcategory,Nodal_Disease,ecog,Chemotherapy,Local_Therapy,Probability of Survival
65.93972603,white,supraglottic,T3,N+,0,no chemo,LP/RT alone,0.366190068
69.42465753,white,supraglottic,T3,N+,0,induction,PLRT,0.396018836
68.14246575,white,supraglottic,T3,N0,3,no chemo,LP/RT alone,0.439289384
40.30410959,white,supraglottic,T3,N+,1,no chemo,LP/RT alone,0.512773973

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is correct to show the legend you have to adjust the margin a little.

```
//rightmargin is set to 200
var margin = {top: 30, right: 200, bottom: 10, left: 10},
```

and width is like

```
 width = 1100 - margin.left - margin.right,
 height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
```

Placement of the legend text as below

```
  var legendRectSize = 10;
  var legendSpacing = 10;
  var legend = d3.select('svg')
.append("g")
.selectAll("g")
.data(color.domain())
.enter()
.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'legend')
  .attr('transform', function(d, i) {
    var height = legendRectSize;
    var x = 900;
    var y = (i * height) + 50;
    return 'translate(' + x + ',' + y + ')';
});
```

That all :)

Working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/00J7Zqkf6Hz95jMbDWLv?p=preview)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much ! This completely works ! I wish I could've thought about the margins before ! Thanks again.